# how to restrict onClicklistener for third party developer?

Tags: android, view

I am creating an  analog watch with help of canvas. I extend view class.
In any view we can implement `onClickListener`.

Is there any method is available by which I can restrict that `onClickListener`.
means no one can implement `onClickListener` with my analog watch.

I tried to override `onClickListener` as final but it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make the class final and override setOnClickListener so that it does what yo want and only what you want... likely nothing.

Comment: @vladimir because i have already tried but it not work.I don't know why??

Comment: what do you mean by not work? You have created subclass? What it is your test for working or not?

Comment: @vladimir mo i mean i have create one class which extends view class and write some method and created a clock it is similar to analog clock provided by android. and i want to use this class in some other class by creating the instance. then I can implement setOnclickListener but i want to restrict that method to user means no one can implement that method with that clock.

Comment: so, making the class final allowed you to subclass your view?